# redirect exmode command to variable

Tags: ex-mode, variables

This is perhaps a beginner question, but I'm unable to (intuitively) figure out how to redirect the output of an ex command to a variable for further processing.

Some background: I'm trying to create a list of file paths that I want to pass to `fzf`, and so I'm concatenating several sources into a list. In effect, what I want is something like this:

```
let list1 = split(system($FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND), "\n")
let list2 = map(range(1, bufnr('$')),'bufname(v:val)')
let list3 = :oldfiles

call fzf#run({'source': list1 + list2,
            \ 'sink': 'e',
            \ })
```

My problem is with the `:oldfiles` list. I can't find the correct syntax to capture the output of that ex command int a local variable `list3`. I've tried the obvious (`let list3 = :oldfiles`) and some other options (`&oldfiles`, `call oldfiles()`, `:oldfiles | list3`, `:oldfiles > list3`, `let list3 = :redir <CR> :oldfiles <CR> :redir END <CR>`, etc. to no avail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure this one out. neovim and modern versions of vim provide an `execute` function that can be used to do just this.

`let list3 = execute(":oldfiles")` does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax for doing this with `redir` (which works in earlier versions of vim than `execute()`) is this:

```
redir => list3
oldfiles
redir END
```

Or if you really want it to be a one liner:

```
redir => list3 | oldfiles | redir END
```

This is described about halfway down the documentation for `:help :redir`.

As for why the other ideas you tried didn't work:

- `&oldfiles`: The `&` syntax allows you to access an option as a variable. `:oldfiles` is an Ex command, not an option.
- `call oldfiles()` would call the `oldfiles()` function, if one existed. Again, `:oldfiles` is an Ex command, not a function.
- `:oldfiles | list` would run the `:oldfiles` command, followed by the `:list3` command (again, if one existed).
- `:oldfiles > list3` As far as I'm aware, this isn't really Vim syntax at all.
- `let list3 = :redir <cr> :oldfiles <CR> :redir END <CR>` This definitely isn't Vim syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Rich. As you can tell, I'm out of my depths in vimland :)

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Don't worry, you'll pick it up quick. Just keep reading through the `:help`!

Comment: Thanks, Rich. How do I see the documentation for a function? E.g. `:help split` shows info on buffer splittinf and nothing about the string splitting function I guessed existed via trial and error.

Comment: In the documentation, tags for functions end with a pair of empty parenthesis. Commands start with a colon. Options are surrounded by single quotes. Insert (/resp command, visual) mode mappings start with a `i_` (/resp `c_`, `v_`). Search patterns start with `/` (-> `:h /\s`). Other tags (normal mode mappings, variables, concepts,...) aren't decorated -- I can't remember of any other exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer `execute()` over `:redir` if you can -- there are less side-effects.

In that particular case, it seems that `v:oldfiles` already contains the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have created a function to get my last 20 commands, as it would be useful here it is:

```
" this function gets last 20 cmds to new buffer
fun! s:RedirHistoryCommands()
    set paste
    redir @r
    history : -20,
    redir End
    new
    put r
    set nopaste
    :%s/^\s\+//g
    :g/^$/d
endfun
command! -nargs=0 GetHistory call s:RedirHistoryCommands()
```

Comment: In my experience: we're better not using `:redir` when we can. In your particular case, you have: `:echo map(range(1, 20), 'histget("cmd", "-".v:val)')`. It's seems a bit convoluted at first, but at least there is no side effect. BTW: `q:` already opens a window where the history is dumped.